# How is it possible that $\textrm{HK}=\textrm{G}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-homomorphism

For the following problem:

> If $\textrm{H}$ and $\textrm{K}$ are distinct subgroups of $\textrm{G}$ of index $2$, then $\textrm{H}\cap\textrm{K}$ is a normal subgroup of $\textrm{G}$ of index $4$.

It is obvious that both $\textrm{H}$ and $\textrm{K}$ are normal subgroups since both have index $2$. Hence their intersection $\textrm{H}\cap\textrm{K}$ is also normal.

The main issue comes with proving that it has an index $4$, using 2nd Isomorphism Theorem. Clearly $\displaystyle\frac{\textrm{H}}{\textrm{H}\cap\textrm{K}}$ is isomorphic to $\displaystyle\frac{\textrm{HK}}{\textrm{K}}$ and using this we can show that $\textrm{H}\cap\textrm{K}$ that index $4$. But on this forum, I have seen another proof of this problem where a person wrote that $\textrm{H}\textrm{K} = \textrm{G}$.

How the heck are they equal? I'm having extreme difficulty in  proving this.

Has this got something to do with both $\textrm{H}$ and $\textrm{K}$ being distinct ?

Comment: $H$ and $K$ are maximal subgroups of $G$. This follows from Lagarange's theorem. Since $H \subset HK$, it follows that $HK=G$.

Comment: An addendum to Crostul's answer: $H$ and $K$ distinct implies $HK \not = H$.

Comment: I suggest you use a less informal title, as it may scare off certain people.

Comment: @Crostul You're invoking Lagrange. Is $G$ assumed finite?

Comment: I couldn't understand how $\textrm{H}$ and $\textrm{K}$ are maximal subgroups and how Lagrange's Theorem invokes $\textrm{HK}=\textrm{G}$, since it is unknown that $\textrm{G}$ is finite.

Comment: Thank you, @Derek Holt, for editing the title. Minto, please avoid language you wouldn't use in front of your professor.

Comment: @Math_QED [If you think THAT'S bad](https://www.scribd.com/doc/18093757/Fuckin-Concrete-Contemporary-Abstract-Algebra-Introduction-by-Nicolas-Bourbaki-Junior?fbclid=IwAR1mvhitPKAyuKSRnNGxtClZvvX1BUE3LrMbN8f-QvFwe0O6rXQpgppgXNA) . . .

Answer (score 2):

We first remark, in general, if $G$ is a group (not necessarily finite) and $H$ is a subgroup of index $2$, $H$ must be normal. This is because the left and right cosets of $H$ necessarily coincide: there is one and only one partition of $G$  into $2$ parts such that one of the parts is $H$.

It follows that for this problem, $H$, $K$, and $H \cap K$ are all normal. In particular, this means $HK$ is a subgroup. It suffices to show that $H \cap K$ has index $2$ in $H$. This will imply that $H \cap K$ has index $4$ in $G$.

Observe that $HK = G$, since $H, K$ are distinct maximal subgroups. Moreover, by one of the isomorphism theorems, we have that $H/(H \cap K) \cong (HK)/K \cong G/K$.  Hence $H \cap K$ has index $2$ in $H$, as desired.

Comment: Good answer! This one is clearest to me so far; @Bernard's, most elegant.

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with $H$ and $K$ being distinct and having index $2$:  these hypotheses imply that none of them is contained in the other. So take an element $h\in H\smallsetminus K$. Then $\;G=hK\cup K$ since $K$ has index $2$. Also, since both $hK,K\subset HK$, we have $G=HK$.

Answer (score 1):

$H,K$ have index $2$. This means that:

1. $H,K$ are normal.
2. $H,K$ are maximal.
   Indeed, let $M$ be a proper subgroup of $G$ containing $H$. Then $M/H$ is a proper subgroup of $G/H$. Since
   $G/H$ is the group with two elements, it follows that $M/H$ is trivial, i.e. $M=H$. The same holds for $K$.
3. By maximality of $H$ and $K$, you have that either $HK=G$ or $HK=H$ or $HK=K$. But the latter two can hold only for $H=HK=K$ (and this contradicts the hypothesis).

Comment: I like the style & format of this answer.